# How is sll implemented in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, hardware, boolean-logic, alu

I don't understand how MIPS would implement the `sll` (shift left logical) instruction using the hardware present in its ALU as shown in the diagrams below. Would anyone be able to clarify what would be happening in it when it's executing an `sll` command? Thanks

[image]
Source: [MIPS ALU](https://ww2.cs.fsu.edu/%7Edennis/teaching/2013_summer_cda3100/week7/week7-day3.pdf)

Comment: Although this site has many people that can answer your question, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ may also help.

Comment: @xiver77 I've just posted the same question there. Here's the link if you want it https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621110/how-is-sll-implemented-in-mips

Comment: Please delete this question. See: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068)